# Eliminar columnas de una tabla que contiene colspan con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando eliminar las dos columnas promedio de la tabla con javascript,
he comprobado que el codigo que tengo me permite eliminar cualquier columna antes del primer colspan pero si intento eliminar una columna despues del primer colspan me dice que no existen mas columnas

```js
let tabla: any = document.getElementById('tabla')

 let row = tabla.rows;       
for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        row[j].deleteCell(2);                      
 }
```

tambien intente eliminar con el queryselector pero nada de resultados

```html
document.querySelector('#tabla .eliminar').remove();
```

Tabla de Ejemplo:

[image: tabla de ejemplo]

```html
<table class="border border-cyan-800" id='tabla>
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Nombre </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Apellido </th>
            <th colspan="3"> Valores iniciales </th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="eliminar"> Promedio inicial </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Media inicial </th>
            <th colspan="3"> Valores finales </th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="eliminar"> Promedio final </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Media final </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Enero </th>
            <th> Febrero </th>
            <th> Marzo </th>
            <th> Abril </th>
            <th> Mayo </th>
            <th> Junio </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td> juan </td>
            <td> perez </td>
            <td> 10 </td>
            <td> 20 </td>
            <td> 30 </td>
            <td class="eliminar"> 30 </td>
            <td> 18 </td>
            <td> 5 </td>
            <td> 8 </td>
            <td> 50 </td>
            <td class="eliminar"> 50 </td>
            <td> 50 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Te falta una comilla en el id de tu tabla, la comilla de cierre

Comment: El `querySelector` y `getElementById` no está encontrando a `#tabla` nunca...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asi se hace, recorres las filas y eliminas la columna por fila

```js
let tabla = document.getElementById('tabla')

 let row = tabla.rows;       
for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        let celdas=row[j].cells
      for (let i = 0; i < celdas.length; i++) {
          if(i==3 || i==5){
            celdas[i].remove();
          }
      }        
        
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="border border-cyan-800" id="tabla">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Nombre </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Apellido </th>
            <th colspan="3"> Valores iniciales </th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="eliminar"> Promedio inicial </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Media inicial </th>
            <th colspan="3"> Valores finales </th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="eliminar"> Promedio final </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Media final </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Enero </th>
            <th> Febrero </th>
            <th> Marzo </th>
            <th> Abril </th>
            <th> Mayo </th>
            <th> Junio </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td> juan </td>
            <td> perez </td>
            <td> 10 </td>
            <td> 20 </td>
            <td> 30 </td>
            <td class="eliminar"> 30 </td>
            <td> 18 </td>
            <td> 5 </td>
            <td> 8 </td>
            <td> 50 </td>
            <td class="eliminar"> 50 </td>
            <td> 50 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha funcionado al 100%